# CSS stacking boxes in columns non-uniformly using grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grids. I want these boxes to stack but not change their height when doing so. Right now, any box adapts the max height of the box beside it. Their shapes should be decided by their inner HTML. How do I make them 'stop' resizing?

This is what's happening right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHXWr.jpg

This is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0T4x.jpg

Comment: look for     `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

Comment: Once I had this problem, but after rereading many articles, I realized that it would be impossible to solve it without a third-party plugin. I even tried `grid-auto-flow: dense;` and it didn't work for me. I solved the problem with the `column-count: 2;` rule by splitting into two columns.